# Actions on Case object in Lightning

Tags: page-layout, lightning-experience, case-object, quickaction

[image]I have created a lightning component and assigned it to a custom case action. How to add this action to header near standard buttons.

- I have added the action in **Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions** section of page layout but it is shown in the feed section.
- Case Close is my action I want it in the button section.

Comment: Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. In particular, use [edit] to add a screen shot as well as illustrate how you configured the Custom case action.

Comment: I am having the same issue. How did you get around this?

Comment: From what I have noticed, if you have a feed based layout for cases the actions will show up in chatter feed section. Else it will show up on top. Could you try that approach once?

Answer (score 18):

There is a catch in case of **cases** and **work orders** objects when it comes to **quick actions**. In the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0) under **Actions on record pages** there is note that says

> Actions on **cases** and **work orders** appear in a different way than on
>   other records. On case and work order records, the page-level action
>   menu contains **custom buttons** and **supported** standard buttons. **Quick
>   actions** appear on the Feed tab.

For other objects, you can **edit page** in the Lightning Experience and then select **Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions** from the selection panel. The panel states

> Actions in this section are predefined by Salesforce. You can **override
>   the predefined actions** to set a customized list of actions on
>   Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience pages that use this layout....

Once you click `override the predefined actions` link, it will give you available actions for SF1 and lightning to use. And then position your lightning-action in your desired sequence, as shown below.
[image]

I worked on the **Account** object for this example, it should be no exception for other objects, and this is what I got

[image]

<strike>It should be **noted** that you can't add more than **three (3)** viewable lightning-actions on the page, as shown in the picture above in *green* square</strike> You can display upto **10** actions on page layout, but other action will available when you click the drop-down next to the last button on the right. There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CP9lQAG) on this to let users **display more Action Buttons on Lightning Highlights Panel**, you can upvote that if it affects you.

### Edit

I have just come across this [Page Layouts in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_migration_customization/units/lex_migration_customization_layouts_ui#topic-title) trailhead and it says

> The highlights panel, which contains key fields for the record, is the only part of a record page that you can’t customize using the page layout editor. The fields in the highlights panel are customized using a **compact layout**.

I just edited the highlights panel using **page layout editor**, strange. May be this trailhead content is old, if someone can put some light on this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you have said is working for Account layout but not for the Case layouts.

Comment: viewable lightning-actions on the page can be handled on Lightning App Builder and the limit is 10.

Comment: I have updated my answer for both of your points. Apparently you can't do that on Cases. If it is that much important, may be you can post an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).

Answer (score 1):

For our case, what we have done , is create a component that we add on our page layout, and this component will contains a set of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can add a quick action on highlight panel on case object lightning record page even if feed tracking is enabled by upgrading to dynamic action which is a new feature in winter 21.

Now, its your choice weather you want to keep action on feed tab or on highlight panel.

Reference: - [ADD QUICK ACTION IN HIGHLIGHT PANEL ON CASE OBJECT LIGHTNING RECORD PAGE EVEN IF FEED TRACKING IS ENABLED](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/12/28/add-quick-action-in-highlight-panel-on-case-object-lightning-record-page-even-if-feed-tracking-is-enabled/)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I have just come across the same issue. For this Just go to Setup-->Object Manager-->'Cases' Object -->Buttons&Actions&Links -->Create a New button or Link--> and after creating this New Button -->Add it to the page layout where you want to see this button --> 
 Go to Fields on the layout  --> Buttons --> Select the Button that you want to Drag.

****IMP NOTE : Don't add it to the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions.****

Just Right below Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions, You can see--> Case Detail --> Custom Buttons --> Drag your Custom Button here. Save the Layout.

If you're still not able to find the button in the Highlights Panel.
Go to Setup --> Feed Tracking--> If Feed Tracking is Enabled --> Go ahead and disable this.
Now go to the "object" and refresh the page to see your custom button added to the Highlights Panel. - Yeshas Konduru